# transition не работает

Tags: css

Есть такой код. Смотрится тут он криво, но суть в том, что при нажатии input блок section становится видимым, но, я хочу, чтобы появлялся блок с эффектом (Медленное появление, или появление сверху вниз, все равно). Но у меня не получается. В чем может быть проблема? Первый раз использую эту функцию если что

```css
section {
    transition-property: all;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
    transition-duration: 2s;
    display: none;
}
input {
  display: none;
}
label {
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 2px;
    margin: 2px;
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
}
label img {
    position: relative;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    filter: grayscale(0.9);
    }
label img:hover {
    filter: grayscale(0);
    }
label:hover {
    color: #888;
    cursor: pointer;
}
input:checked + label img{
  filter: grayscale(0);
}
#tab1:checked ~ #content1,
#tab2:checked ~ #content2,
#tab3:checked ~ #content3,
#tab4:checked ~ #content4 {
    transition-property: all;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
    transition-duration: 2s;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    background: blue;
    transition: top 1s ease-out 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="preutx">
<input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" checked>
<label for="tab1"><img src="img/heroes/Ringo/double-down.png"></label>
<input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs">
<label for="tab2"><img src="img/heroes/Ringo/achilles-shot.png"></label>
<input id="tab3" type="radio" name="tabs">
<label for="tab3"><img src="img/heroes/Ringo/twirling-silver.png"></label>
<input id="tab4" type="radio" name="tabs">
<label for="tab4"><img src="img/heroes/Ringo/hellfire-brew.png"></label>

<!-- Content -->
<section id="content1">
    <p>
      Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet beef venison beef ribs kielbasa. Sausage pig leberkas, t-bone sirloin shoulder bresaola. Frankfurter rump porchetta ham. Pork belly prosciutto brisket meatloaf short ribs.
    </p>
    <p>
      Brisket meatball turkey short loin boudin leberkas meatloaf chuck andouille pork loin pastrami spare ribs pancetta rump. Frankfurter corned beef beef tenderloin short loin meatloaf swine ground round venison.
    </p>
  </section>
  <section id="content2">
    <p>
     yjeytjetyj rump porchetta ham. Pork belly prosciutto brisket meatloaf short ribs.
    </p>
    <p>
      Brisket meatball turkey short loin boudin leberkas meatloaf chuck andouille pork loin pastrami spare riyjtyjtyejy Frankfurter corned beef beef tenderloin short loin meatloaf swine ground round venison.
    </p>
  </section>   </div>
```

Comment: transition не работает с `display: none;`
Пробуйте вместо `display: none;` прятать блок с помощью`opacity:0; z-index:1` и задать бэкграунд родителю

Comment: хмм а если высоту на 0 поставить но дисплей оставить?

Comment: Как вариант, только `transition` не любит автоматически рассчитанные величины анимировать, например `height: auto` в `height: 20px`

Comment: у меня получилось с height 0 в auto идет переход плавный. Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на другой input, этот переход был в обратную сторону, перед выходом нового контента?

Comment: задержку ( `transition-delay` )  используйте. В стилях по умолчанию задержка равна нулю, что бы схлопывался сразу, а в `#tab1:checked ~ #content...` ставьте равную скорости "схлопования"

Comment: чего то не получается

Comment: `transition: top 1s ease-out 0.5s;` Вот это вообще лишнее судя по всему=)

Comment: убрал уже это, не видно разницы все равно =( только задержку и видно)))

Comment: Закиньте код например [сюда](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pasha_sergeev/2LujxqLz/ здесь интересно текст исчезает и появляется, а вот фон нет. у меня в хроме только появляется и моментально исчезает

Comment: Держите: https://jsfiddle.net/2LujxqLz/1/

Comment: transition лучше исползовать с height: 0;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых `transition на display:none;` не срабатывает...

`display:(должен быть не)none`;

Во-вторых тут не хватает запятой  `transition: top 1s ЗАПЯТАЯ ease-out 0.5s;`

В третьих у вас тут в коде есть `"top 1s"`, а почему не прописали позицию `TOP:Npx;`

В четвертых, если вы использовали `display:none;`, что-бы элемента не было видно, то лучше уж `opacity`

Answer (score 0):

`transition` работает с `visibility`.